# How can we determine why our tag edits are being rejected?

Tags: support

I'm on my second try entering content for a tag excerpt on this site.  Who is rejecting these, and how can I find out why?  My first try must have been really bad for someone to decide that having something is worse than having nothing!  I've never had a tag edit rejected on any other site.

Comment: Also, see Robert Cartaino's answer [here](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36/lets-write-tag-wikis-sort-of/45#45) and the links in it. And I, too, had an edit rejected at first! My suggestion for improving it: make sure that it's very well tied into engineering, but still explains what kinds of questions it might be used for.

Comment: feetwet, The comments/answers so far pretty much answer your question, but don't take it personally. Wiki excerpts are tricky at first until the community finally "gets it" (and they always do). As for your your edits being "worse than nothing", it's not quite as harsh as that. Once there's an entry in place, folks *are* more inclined to leave it as is, clearing it out completely is just a more-definite indication for folks to try again. This is just one of those private-beta things that we all have to work through. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here:  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/123

Robert Cartaino rejected the edit and stated:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used.

Which is pretty standard grounds for rejecting a tag edit within SE.  There's some Meta.SE guidance to that effect.

And I found that by going to your [suggestions activity page](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/77/feetwet?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

---

Looking at your other suggested edits, I would venture a guess that they'll be rejected too.  Excerpts should provide guidance on *when* to use a particular tag as well as explaining what the tag represents.